# Powershell Script to Backup Bookmarks / Favorite to a different drive for IE, Edge, & Chrome

Tags: powershell, backup, bookmarks

I'm looking for a PowerShell script I can schedule that will automatically backup all my Favorites/Bookmarks from IE, Edge, and Chrome to a separate drive in case my laptop gets hosed.

Can anyone help me with this? I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Chrome and Edge both back up your bookmarks to the cloud if you sign into the browsers, any specific reason you need a PowerShell script to copy to a separate drive?

Comment: Why not just use file history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script [EdgeChromium-Bookmarks-Backup-JSON-to-HTML.ps1](https://github.com/gunnarhaslinger/Microsoft-Edge-based-on-Chromium-Scripts/blob/master/EdgeChromium-Bookmarks-Backup-JSON-to-HTML.ps1) accomplishes what you asked for Edge (I have not tried Chrome but I assume that it might also work).

It was written for EdgeChromium Beta 78, however it still works for the Edge versions up to 91 at the time of this writing.

You need to modify the line:

```
$JSON_File_Path = "$env:localappdata\Microsoft\Edge Beta\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
```

to

```
$JSON_File_Path = "$env:localappdata\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
```

and create a folder named `backup` on the following path `$env:userprofile\backup` (`C:\Users\Username\backup` change Username with your user name)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try it out and see how it goes!

Comment: @user335185 Note that the script only does the backup.

Comment: I can import from the backup though right? Would it keep everything in the same folders and such? Thanks!

Comment: @user335185 It creates a html file with that contains your bookmarks as links. Unfortunately, it does not create folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me, but I'll still give you the correct answer since no one else contributed. For now, I continue to manually backup my bookmarks. I wanted a method to automatically backup my Chrom, IE, & Edge bookmarks/favorites in a scheduled task automatically. I just couldn't get it to work. Thank you regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to work with Edge v98 and sorted the favorites bar issue.
[GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/gunnarhaslinger/Microsoft-Edge-based-on-Chromium-Scripts/blob/e049f1ef1ec957f9c74bd893ffb8cb09ad1c4be0/EdgeChromium-Bookmarks-Backup-JSON-to-HTML.ps1)

```
# Read EdgeChromium Bookmarks (JSON File) and Export/Backup to HTML File
# Gunnar Haslinger, 30.10.2019 - tested width EdgeChromium Beta 78
# SCCMOG - Richie Schuster, 2022.02.08 - Tested with Edge Chromium 98.0.1108.43 - https://github.com/SCCMOG - SCCMOG.com

# Path to EdgeChromium Bookmarks File and HTML Export
$JSON_File_Path = "$($env:localappdata)\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
$ExportedTime = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm'
$HTML_File_Root = "c:\admin"
$HTML_File_Path = "$($HTML_File_Root)\EdgeChromium-Bookmarks.backup_$($ExportedTime).html"
# Reference-Timestamp needed to convert Timestamps of JSON (Milliseconds / Ticks since LDAP / NT epoch 01.01.1601 00:00:00 UTC) to Unix-Timestamp (Epoch)
$Date_LDAP_NT_EPOCH = Get-Date -Year 1601 -Month 1 -Day 1 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0

if (!(Test-Path -Path $JSON_File_Path -PathType Leaf)) {
    throw "Source-File Path $JSON_File_Path does not exist!" 
}
if (!(Test-Path -Path $HTML_File_Root -PathType Container)) { 
    throw "Destination-Root Path $HTML_File_Root does not exist!" 
}

# ---- HTML Header ----
$BookmarksHTML_Header = @'
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
'@

$BookmarksHTML_Header | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Force -Encoding utf8

# ---- Enumerate Bookmarks Folders ----
Function Get-BookmarkFolder {
    [cmdletbinding()] 
    Param( 
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        $Node 
    )
    function ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp {
        param(
            [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
            $TimeStamp 
        )
        $date = [Decimal] $TimeStamp
        if ($date -gt 0) { 
            $date = $Date_LDAP_NT_EPOCH.AddTicks($date * 10)
            $date = $date | Get-Date -UFormat %s 
            $unixTimeStamp = [int][double]::Parse($date) - 1
            return $unixTimeStamp
        }
    }   
    if ($node.name -like "Favorites Bar") {
        $DateAdded = [Decimal] $node.date_added | ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp
        $DateModified = [Decimal] $node.date_modified | ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp
        "        <DT><H3 FOLDED ADD_DATE=`"$($DateAdded)`" LAST_MODIFIED=`"$($DateModified)`" PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER=`"true`">$($node.name )</H3>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
        "        <DL><p>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
    }
    foreach ($child in $node.children) {
        $DateAdded = [Decimal] $child.date_added | ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp    
        $DateModified = [Decimal] $child.date_modified | ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp
        if ($child.type -eq 'folder') {
            "        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE=`"$($DateAdded)`" LAST_MODIFIED=`"$($DateModified)`">$($child.name)</H3>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
            "        <DL><p>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
            Get-BookmarkFolder $child # Recursive call in case of Folders / SubFolders
            "        </DL><p>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
        }
        else {
            # Type not Folder => URL
            "        <DT><A HREF=`"$($child.url)`" ADD_DATE=`"$($DateAdded)`">$($child.name)</A>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Encoding utf8
        }
    }
    if ($node.name -like "Favorites Bar") {
        "        </DL><p>" | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
    }
}

# ---- Convert the JSON Contens (recursive) ----
$data = Get-content $JSON_File_Path -Encoding UTF8 | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json
$sections = $data.roots.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
ForEach ($entry in $sections) { 
    $data.roots.$entry | Get-BookmarkFolder
}

# ---- HTML Footer ----
'</DL>' | Out-File -FilePath $HTML_File_Path -Append -Force -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).